# How to fix: The operator & is undefined for the argument type(s) int, boolean

Tags: java

I am trying to find the highest no using & operator in my code

My current machine is 64-bit. However, I have tried a similar code on another machine with a 32-bit operating system and where it works fine.  Is there a possibility I am facing this issue due to the Operating system

```
int a1 = 100;
int b1 = 200;
int c1 = 300;

//nested if-else

for(a1>b1 & a1>c1){ 
    System.out.println("a1 is the greatest");
}
else if(b1>c1){
    System.out.println("b1 is the greatest");
}
else{
    System.out.println("C1 is the greatest");
}
```

Actual result: getting below error on line: `for(a1>b1 & a1>c1)`

Error message: `The operator & is undefined for the argument type(s) int, boolean`

Expected Result: This error should not come

Comment: The correct operator is `&&` (logical AND) not `&` (bitwise AND)

Comment: The only issue with the code is the `for` needs to be `if`. There is no reason it should work differently on a 32 vs 64 bit machine. I don't even see how any different versions of Java could change it.

Comment: What does this have to do with maven (and pom.xml)?

Comment: The problem is not the & it is the fact that you used `for` instead of `if`

Comment: Thank you all for the prompt response!  Problem resolved by replacing for with if keyword

Answer (score 2):

Two issues:
<s>You’re looking for a logical AND (&&), not a bitwise AND (&)</s> This was not the issue due to the order of operations (thanks WJS for pointing this out)
That for statement should be an if.

Comment: My Problem got resolved by simply using "if" keyword instead of "for". Thank you so much guys.

Comment: Hey @YogeshKumarThakur please mark this answer if it solved the problem. :)

Comment: @WJS 1: I didn't read the comments, my bad. 2: Guess I need to brush up on my orders of operations.

Answer (score 1):

Ok.  Time to clear something up.

As I said in my comment, you should use an `if` instead of a `for`

Regarding the `&`, it is perfectly fine to use it in an if statement but
can lead to some unnecessary processing.

The `&&` and `||` are short circuiting logical operators.

The `&` and `|` are non-short circuiting logical operators.  So

```xml
int a = 0;
if (false & a++) {
   // dead code
}
a now equals 1 because it was not short circuited (the a++ was evaluated).

int a = 0;
if (false && a++) {
   // dead code
}

a still equals 0 because the if was `short circuited`. Since 
false && anything is false, there is no reason to evaluate
 the rest of the logical if.
```

And `&` and `|` can also be used to do bitwise processing in the `proper context`